# ASP.NET MVC jQuery Validation scripts bundles error

Tags: jquery-validate, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation

I'm having trouble deploying my application to a UAT server. The code has been working fine on my machine for months. When I run the application I get and exception error but no real useful information. The error just says 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key'.

[image: VS 2013 code debugger view with error]

I can provide the stack trace if needed but I don't think it will help. I did a search and others have had success by updating the Microsoft.aspnet.web.Optimization package. I did update the package but Nuget already says I have 1.1.3 installed.

For reference here is a snippet of my BundleConfig.cs file. It has this in it:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
           "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
           "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to show us the ***relevant rendered*** HTML and JavaScript as seen in the browser source.  Then we can know if the problem is within the HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: Wait, isn't the `unobtrusive` validation plugin supposed to be included _after_ the jQuery Validate plugin?

Comment: @Sparky The build fails so I can't show you the rendered HTML. Also I haven't changed the bundle definition. I don't remember changing it from the generated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just recreating the whole application in another solution copying/pasting the code. An extreme solution but it worked.